# TypeScript не видит symbol-свойства

Tags: javascript, typescript

... при этом `Symbol` прекрасно работает с интерфейсами.

```
const symbol_property = Symbol()

type SomeType = { prop: number }

interface SomeInterface {
  normal_property: SomeType | null
  [symbol_property]: SomeType | null
}

class Some implements SomeInterface {

  normal_property: SomeType | null = null;
  [symbol_property]: SomeType | null = null;

  normal():number | null {
    if (!this.normal_property) return null
    return this.normal_property.prop++
  }

  symbol(): number | null {
    if (!this[symbol_property]) return null
    return this[symbol_property].prop++
    // error -> Object is possibly 'null'
  }

  fun(): number | null {
    const sp = this[symbol_property]
    if (!sp) return null
    return sp.prop++
  }

}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeBbARiANgfQA4CcRYFMcp4YBeGAZSVTQAoBKAWAChWTCqRECAVeThQDeMXPgBcMMAFcURGAF9WrAJZgoRAGYBDYAS48Akuq279Q1jCkgcibZjGFi8SZW58B+gD5TpaNJYwANoIKOjYeE4kALqu7vycPjL+rEpsLMBo2hAQBvoqiFhoBDzquW5GJjg6ejAW6VZgNnYOkUQkcTwJ3r7+5L1oANyBITThju3wsXndMEl+aP3JQ8osjc32jOIycjhzA3WBViqaMHQAhFAAFioQAHRNtvYR+JMMMDgEUNI4YANHHy+Pz+11uDw2rVezjujgA1LDAmlAqFaFtfLt9stDmsrDATmdLjcIKMwpColN3p9vr9-jirFTgTBQcSUeM2s5ojDIvCAQB6XkwIh4PYAWgAfDAAPLIABWBGAsFuohAORUyDQpAA5MtNYjVlZNNIwGidsh5PM+vVcTBQJBYBAsP1mSTaC9ydEAfiLg7KUCacsAQyaQ6ufgeTikSwFEA)

Это вообще возможно как-то исправить?
TypeScript - 4.4.0-dev.20210601

Comment: решение в лоб - вынести в переменную и проверять переменную

Comment: @Grundy Так в последней функции примера я так и сделал. Обидно что методы бывают с одной строкой, где либо оператор утверждения `!`, и смотреть на предупреждения, либо добавлять лишнюю строку :(.